# PHP: get a qr image from google charts + insert in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, image, echo

Visit http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chld=L|1&chl=hello

Here is an example of a QR-code I want to retrieve and insert into my MySQL database. I would like to keep everything neat and tidy in a MySQL database, therefore, I want to insert the image directly after it has been created.

The whole process:

1. Get a qr-image from the google api.
2. Store it on a variable.
3. Insert it in a database.
4. Retrieve it from the database and echo on the screen.

This is my code. Echoing $img does not work too.

```
$qrUrl = "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chld=L|1&chl=hello"

$qr     = file_get_contents($qrUrl);

$img  = imagecreatefromstring($qr);
```

After which I try to insert it into the database.

Which mistakes am I making here?

Thanks in advance,

Eltyer

Comment: Hmmm... I thought that API was deprecated?

Comment: I read that too, but it still works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you attempting to  to echo $img?

```
echo $img; // will not work

echo '<img src="'.$qrUrl.'" />'; // should work
```

Then you need something like:

```
$filename = "youFileName.png";
$url = urlencode("stringToEncode");
$qr  = file_get_contents("http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=100x100&cht=qr&chl=$url");
file_put_contents($filename, $qr);

echo '<img src="$filename" />';
```

Comment: Hey fox, thanks for reacting. Your suggestion does work. Do you also have a suggestion to get this image from the google API and into the database?

Comment: Expanded on answer. Now you will actually have the image as a file. I would not store the image in your db - just its name.